# Flex item renderer- don't include element if null?

Tags: apache-flex, formatting, mxml, itemrenderer

I have item renderer code like this:

```
<s:HGroup>
    <s:Label text="{data.DateTime}"/>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Label text="{data.Description}"/>
        <s:Label text="{data.Amount}"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:HGroup>
```

Description is an optional field.. I would like if the Description field is null for the Amount field to move up, but right now there is just an empty space.  Is there any way to achieve this in mxml? I want them in separate fields because I plan to make the Description editable, but the Amount fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote simple application that simulates a behaviour of Item renderer.
The trick is to use **visible** and **includeInLayout** properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.charts.DateTimeAxis;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var data:Object;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var newData:Object = new Object();
                newData.DateTime = new Date();
                newData.Description = "Description";
                newData.Amount = 12345;
                data = newData;
            }           


            protected function setNull_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var newData:Object = new Object();
                newData.DateTime = new Date();
                newData.Description = null;
                newData.Amount = 12345;
                data = newData;

            }


            protected function setValue_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var newData:Object = new Object();
                newData.DateTime = new Date();
                newData.Description = "Description";
                newData.Amount = 12345;
                data = newData;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <s:VGroup>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Button id="setNull" label="Set Null" click="setNull_clickHandler(event)"/>
            <s:Button id="setValue" label="Set Description" click="setValue_clickHandler(event)"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:Label text="Renderer"/>      
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Label text="{data.DateTime}"/>
            <s:VGroup>
                <s:Label text="{data.Description}"
                         visible="{data.Description != null}"
                         includeInLayout="{data.Description != null}"
                         />
                <s:Label text="{data.Amount}" />
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:HGroup> 
    </s:VGroup> 
</s:Application>
```